# grouped COUNT in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, rank

I'm trying to get a SUM of a grouped Count.

```
SELECT ig_idx,ig_team1,ig_team2benefit,ig_game_type
FROM (select ig_idx,ig_team1,ig_team2benefit,ig_game_type,
RANK() OVER(partition by ig_root,ig_game_type order by ig_idx asc) AS rank
FROM  info_game ) AS t1
WHERE rank < 2

==================================
idx name        odds    type
----------------------------------
1   Kjelsaas    1.4     dnb
2   Kjelsaas    1.75    1x2
3   Kjelsaas    1.75    ou
4   Kjelsaas    1.8     ah
5   Grorud      3       dnb
6   Grorud      3.8     1x2
7   Grorud      1.36    ou
8   Grorud      2.075   ah
9   Brumunddal  2.25    1x2
10  Brumunddal  1.57    ou
11  Brumunddal  2.2     ah
==================================
```

I want a result this.

```
==================================
idx name        odds    type count
----------------------------------
1   Kjelsaas    1.4     dnb    4
2   Kjelsaas    1.75    1x2    4
3   Kjelsaas    1.75    ou     4
4   Kjelsaas    1.8     ah     4
5   Grorud      3       dnb    2
6   Grorud      3.8     1x2    2
9   Brumunddal  2.25    1x2    3
10  Brumunddal  1.57    ou     3
11  Brumunddal  2.2     ah     3
==================================
```

Comment: The first query returns your example data? If so what happened to the 2 Grorud rows? Should Grorud count be 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your query returns the first table results? You can do this:

```
with cte_example 
as
(SELECT ig_idx,ig_team1,ig_team2benefit,ig_game_type
FROM (select ig_idx,ig_team1,ig_team2benefit,ig_game_type,
RANK() OVER(partition by ig_root,ig_game_type order by ig_idx asc) AS rank
FROM  info_game ) AS t1
WHERE rank < 2)

select *
       ,count(name) over(partition by name) count
from cte_example
```

or maybe you can just put the `count...over` function within your derived table? There are many ways to do this. Or is your query the attempt and the first table is data sample to make it look like the latter?